# If $x_n \to x$ and $y_n \to y$ weakly. Then $\langle x, y\rangle = \lim_n \langle x_n, y_n\rangle$

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, alternative-proof, weak-convergence, weak-topology

I'm trying to show below property, i.e.,

> Let $(H, \langle \cdot, \cdot\rangle)$ be a real Hilbert space. Let $x,y, x_n, y_n\in H$ such that $x_n \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} x$ and $y_n \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} y$ in the weak topology $\sigma(H, H^*)$. Then $\langle x, y\rangle = \lim_n \langle x_n, y_n\rangle$.

1. Could you have a check on my below attempt?
2. Is there another way that does not use below lemma?

Thank you so much for your help!

---

Let $\sigma (H, H^*) \otimes \sigma (H, H^*)$ be the product topology of $\sigma (H, H^*)$ and itself.

> [Lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4362367/a-simpler-proof-of-sigma-e-e-star-boxtimes-sigma-f-f-star-sigma-bige) $\sigma (H, H^*) \otimes \sigma (H, H^*)= \sigma (H^2, (H^2)^*)$.

By above **Lemma**, $(x_n, y_n) \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} (x, y)$ in $\sigma (H^2, (H^2)^*)$. Clearly, the map $(u, v) \mapsto \langle u, v \rangle$ belongs to $(H^2)^*$. The claim then follows.

Comment: Sorry - could you explain what $\sigma(H,H^\ast)$ is precisely?

Comment: I don't think this is true. However , I might be wrong. Maybe you can use the Riemann Lebesgue Lemma to come up with some counter examples in $L^{2}[0,2\pi]$ . What is true is that if $x_{n}\xrightarrow{w} x$ and $y_{n}\to y$ then $\langle x_{n},y_{n}\rangle \to \langle x,y\rangle$ by just noting that $||x_{n}||$ is bounded by UBP and then using Cauchy-Schwartz

Comment: @esoteric-elliptic $H^*$ is the continuous dual of $H$, and $\sigma(H, H^*)$ is the coarsest topology on $H$ such that every $f \in H^*$ is continuous w.r.t. $\sigma(H, H^*)$. Please see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_topology#Weak_topology_induced_by_the_continuous_dual_space).

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron Even the statement is not true, I would love to see where is the logical mistake in my argument...

Comment: @Analyst I see. Let me think .

Comment: Wait @Analyst $(u,v)\mapsto \langle u,v\rangle $ is not even a linear map. It is a Bilinear map .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement is not true in general. Consider $L^{2}[0,2\pi]$ . Take $x_{n}=\sin(nx)$ and $y_{n}=(-1)^{n}\sin(nx)$

Then for any $v\in L^{2}[0,1]$ , $\langle v,x_{n}\rangle$ and $\langle v,y_{n}\rangle $ tend to $0$ by Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma. $\langle f,g\rangle =\int_{0}^{2\pi}f(x)g(x)\,\,d\lambda(x)$

But   $\langle x_{n},y_{n}\rangle $ is positive for $n$ odd and negative for $n$ even . Hence is not convergent

What is true is that if one of the sequences say $x_{n}\to x$ , i.e. $||x_{n}-x||\to 0$ . Then you have $\langle x_{n},y_{n}\rangle -\langle x,y\rangle = \langle x_{n}-x,y_{n}\rangle +\langle x,y_{n}\rangle-\langle x,y\rangle$ .

Now as $y_{n}$ converges weakly, it is norm bounded by Uniform Boundedness Principle. Thus $||y_{n}||\leq C$

So by Cauchy-Schwartz $|\langle x_{n}-x,y_{n}\rangle|\leq ||x_{n}-x||\cdot||y_{n}||\leq C||x_{n}-x||\to 0$ and also $\langle x,y_{n}\rangle-\langle x,y\rangle \to 0$ .

Thus you have $\langle x_{n},y_{n}\rangle \to \langle x,y\rangle$

Answer (score 4):

Any orthonormal sequence $e_n$ tends to $0$ weakly, due to the Bessel inequality. But $\langle e_n,e_n\rangle =1.$

Comment: Ah . lol . I was overthinking it. Maybe in the back of my mind, I was thinking of $x_{n}$ and $y_{n}$ to be distinct sequences. But your example is short and sweet.

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron Thanks. Your example is based on the same idea. I can  take, as you did, $f_n=e^{in}e_n,$ to spoil the convergence of $\langle e_n,f_n\rangle$ whatsoever, as the sequence $e^{in}$ is dense in the unit circle.

Comment: Yeah exactly. In Hilbert space theory, sometimes the relation that $\langle v,e_{n}\rangle\to 0$ is itself called Riemann Lebesgue Lemma. Using Bessel's Inequality, the proof is easier however than the standard real analysis proof.